# Remesh modifier on curve does not work

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

[image]

I just saw https://cloud.blender.org/p/settlers/5e7e343c129c886f23af503a and wanted to try it out myself. as you can see in the video: the curve (it's actually still a curve, not converted to a mesh) has a remesh modifier on it and is then shrinkwrapped onto the sphere.

when I do that, it does not work: https://streamable.com/c9fyrz

what am I doing differently / wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I read this question and try it myself, after lot of trials and errors, I found the settings that I think get close to the video are:

1. Curve type: 2D, give it extrude value of 0.01m
2. Remesh modifier with Sharp mode, Octree Depth: 5, Scale: 0.6, and Sharpness: 0.1
3. Shrinkwrap modifier with Offset of 0.01m
4. This one is optional, but I think this is what they do in the video: check Wireframe in Object properties > Viewport Display.